# Trying to output a list of unique data-attributes (jQuery/Java)

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a grid of products, and I'm trying to build a dynamic filtering system by assigning each of them data attributes (data-category="" data-department="" data-color="" etc). I need to output a ul of each of these data attributes containing the only the unique options (so "Small, Medium, Large" even though there are multiple instances of each, and some products may have more than one (pipe separated) attribute)

Example:

```
<div data-category="shorts" data-size="large" data-color="blue"></div> 
<div data-category="shorts" data-size="small|medium|large" data-color="green"></div>
<div data-category="shorts" data-size="small" data-color="green|red"></div>
<div data-category="shirts" data-size="medium" data-color="blue"></div>
<div data-category="sunglasses" data-color="black"></div>
```

For this data I'm trying to get three lists,

Category: shorts, shirts, sunglasses
Size: large, medium, small
Color: blue, green, red

And stick them into lists elements.

Comment: is it a theoretical question??

Comment: Added an example, the code I've already built is so ugly and half baked that I don't wanna even copy and paste it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried very basic Approcah, but it will help you to understand

#### HTML

```
<div data-category="shorts" data-size="large" data-color="blue"></div> 
<div data-category="shorts" data-size="large" data-color="green"></div>
<div data-category="shorts" data-size="small" data-color="red"></div>
<div data-category="shirts" data-size="medium" data-color="blue"></div>
<div data-category="sunglasses" data-color="black"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function(){
     var output =[];
     var $cat =[]; 
     var $size = [];
     var $color =[];
    $('div').map(function (i){
        
        if( typeof $(this).data('category') == 'string') 
            $cat[i] = $(this).data('category')
        if( typeof $(this).data('size') == 'string') 
            $size[i] = $(this).data('size')
        if( typeof $(this).data('color') == 'string') 
        $color[i] = $(this).data('color');

    });
    output.push($.unique($cat),$.unique($size),$.unique($color));
    console.log(output); //or use alert(output)

})
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/sFWa4/)

**Function Reference**

[`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

[`$.unique`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

[`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me quite a bit. Apologies for the delay in accepting your answer.